# Comma operator returns first value instead of second in argument list?

Tags: javascript, operators, comma-operator

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) claims that:

> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right)
>   and **returns the value of the second operand**.

However, when I tried running `<script> alert(1, 2); </script>`, it shows a "1" instead of a "2".

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the context of a function call, the comma is used to separate parameters from each other. So what you're doing is passing a second parameter to `alert()` which gets silently ignored.

What you want is possible this way:

```
 alert((1,2));
```

The extra brackets form a parameter on their own; inside them you can use the comma as an operator.

Answer (score 6):

Comma`(,)` is also a parameter separator.

Use `alert((1,2))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

When you use it like that, the comma is not an operator, it's a separator between the parameters in the call to the `alert` method.

If you put parentheses around them so that it's an expression, it will show you `2`:

```
alert( (1,2) );
```