# JavaScript syntax (0, fn)(args)

Tags: javascript

Just checking Google's JavaScript code and I've found this syntax:

```
var myVar = function...;
(0, myVar)(args);
```

Do you know the meaning of this syntax?
I cannot find the difference between
`(0, myVar)(args);`
and
`myVar(args);`.

To give an exact example, we have

```
_.x3 = function (a, b) {
    return new _.q3(20 * b.x + a.B.B.x, 20 * b.y + a.B.B.y)
};
```

And later

```
this.ta = new _.s3((0, _.x3)(this.fa, this.B.B), 0);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript comma operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580596/javascript-comma-operator)

Comment: Out of curiousity, can you post more of the context of where this appears?

Comment: I was checking the code of https://www.google.fr/xjs/_/js/s/sy46,zr/rt=j/ver=-wnZQEUYm8E.en_US./d=0/rs=AItRSTNMBUOhWluxPqsKFY9CVTnMlxNz6w

Comment: @korko I edited my answer if it will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does google main page use (0, func)(args) syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535601/why-does-google-main-page-use-0-funcargs-syntax)

Comment: ^ that makes the questions possible duplicates of each other from both ends. In rails terms, you get a stack level too deep error

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I had the same question and then found the answer, as follows:

It really is for

```
(0, foo.fn)();
```

Remember that in JavaScript, when `foo.fn()` is invoked, then inside of `fn`, the `this` is bound to `foo`.  If you use

```
var g = foo.fn;
g();
```

then when `g` is invoked above, the `this` is bound to the global object (`window`, in the context of a web browser).

So do you need to define `g` like above?  Can you do something such as

```
(foo.fn)();
```

The answer is no. JavaScript will treat it the same as `foo.fn();` as it is just `foo.fn` with the redundant `()` that can be removed.

But there is one way to get around it, and it is exactly to use [the comma operator, which Mozilla stated as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand

So using

```
(0, foo.fn)();
```

the `(0, foo.fn)` will get evaluated to a reference to the function, like `g` above, and then the function is invoked. And then, `this` is not bound to `foo` but is bound to the global object.

So the code written this way, is to "cut the binding".

Example:

```js
var foo = { 
              fullName: "Peter", 
              sayName:  function() { console.log("My name is", this.fullName); } 
          };

window.fullName = "Shiny";

foo.sayName();       // My name is Peter

(foo.sayName)();     // My name is Peter

(0, foo.sayName)();  // My name is Shiny
```

Now why would some code want to cut the binding?  I read that in some case, if we have a function:

```
function foo() {
  // using `this` here
}
```

Then the `this` would point to the global object.  But if `foo()` together with other functions and values, are packaged into a module, then when the function is invoked using

```
someModule.foo();
```

Then the `this` is bound to `someModule`, and it has changed the behavior of `foo()`. So to keep `foo()` as original as it is, we cut the binding, so that inside of `foo()`, the `this` is bound to the global object like before.

Comment: JavaScript being predictable as usual :'D

Comment: the expression could be anything returning the function `(foo.sayName || 0)()` would work the same, and so would `(() => foo.sayName)()()`

Answer (score 4):

This syntax is using the comma operator, `,`. It evaluate all of its operands and returns the value of the last one. In this case, 0 is just being used as a placeholder so `(0, function() {})` will return `(function() {})`. After it is evaluated, the `(args)` part is invoking the function and giving it its arguments.

**Edit after comment:**

The reason one would use this style of coding is so that they can execute the code quickly or on one line. Here is an example:

```
var a = 0,
    b = 1,
    c;

c = ( a++, b++, a + 2 ); // a is added, b is added, and a is added then returned

a; // 1
b; // 2
c; // 3
```

Comment: Yeah, absolutely a good reason but... 0 means nothing. Is there some kind of protection, descoping or something giving a meaning for (0, fn)() instead of just fn().

Comment: Sorry, but I can't think of any. I'm sure there's a reason though if Google's using it.

Comment: Just a small clarification: Evaluation of `(0, function() {})` is here the same as Evaluation of `(function() {})`, *only* because Evaluation of `function() {}` happens to return a function object. As such, I would be careful saying that `(0, function() {})` returns `(function() {})`. In reality, the flow is as such: Evaluation of *ParenthesizedExpression* > Evaluation of inner expression, here a *CommaExpression*, which returns the value of the second operand (calls *GetValue*). Evaluation of `(0, foo.bar)` does not equal Evaluation of `(foo.bar)`, for instance (see accepted answer for info).