# Why does babel rewrite imported function call to (0, fn)(...)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Given an input file like

```js
import { a } from 'b';

function x () {
  a()
}
```

babel will compile it to

```js
'use strict';

var _b = require('b');

function x() {
  (0, _b.a)();
}
```

but when compiled in loose mode the function call is output as `_b.a();`

I've done some research into where the comma operator is added in the hope there was a comment explaining it.
The code responsible for adding it is [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/91fb64eaf53c67a7ed7605aab71f8dcaa4d39ae2/packages/babel/src/transformation/modules/lib/remaps.js#L32).

Comment: They should've done `_b.a.call()` to make the intention clear.

Comment: @Bergi I'm sure the reason they it with (0, ) is to save space in the transpiled code.

Comment: see also [Does the comma operator influence the execution context in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36076794/1048572)

Comment: see also [JavaScript syntax (0, fn)(args)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11541134/1048572)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

`(0, _b.a)()` ensures that the function `_b.a` is called with `this` set to the global object (or if strict mode is enabled, to `undefined`). If you were to call `_b.a()` directly, then `_b.a` is called with `this` set to `_b`.

`(0, _b.a)();` is equivalent to

```
0; // Ignore result
var tmp = _b.a;
tmp();
```

(the `,` is the comma operator, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: thanks for the link. passed over this so many times and finally decided to find out what was happening.

Comment: @RobW I would think adding `var _a = (0, _b.a)` at the top of the file and then calling `_a` would save more space in a lot of cases, any idea they didn't do that?

Comment: @Andy Your suggestion may have side effects, e.g. when `_b.a` is a (dynamic) getter.

Comment: @RobW I see, so you're saying to idea is to avoid potential side effects until the function needs to be called.

Comment: Notice that modules are always strict code, so it's always `this === undefined` and you don't even need to mention the global object

Comment: if the goal is to access the global this object, would using an arrow function achieve the same result?

Comment: @JonathandeM. In general, no, using an arrow function is NOT equivalent to `(0, fn)()`. Arrow functions have a fixed "this" value, fixed to the `this` of the scope where the arrow function was defined. The `this` of an arrow function will therefore only resolve to the global object it was defined in the global scope of a classic script (opposed to a module script), or if the `this` of the scope where the arrow function was defined already resolved to the global object.

Answer (score 38):

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the last operand.

```
console.log((1, 2)); // Returns 2 in console
console.log((a = b = 3, c = 4)); // Returns 4 in console
```

So, let see an example:

```
var a = {
  foo: function() {
    console.log(this === window);
  }
};

a.foo(); // Returns 'false' in console
(0, a.foo)(); // Returns 'true' in console
```

Now, in `foo` method, `this` is equal to `a` (because `foo` is attached to `a`). So if you call `a.foo(`) directly, it will log `false` in console.

But, if you were call `(0, a.foo)()`. The expression `(0, a.foo)` will evaluate each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand. In other words, `(0, a.foo)` is equivalent to

```
function() {
  console.log(this === window);
}
```

Since this function no longer is attached to anything, its `this` is the global object `window`. That's why it log `true` in console when call `(0, a.foo)()`.

Comment: running `console.log(this === window);` in dev console does't log print anymore.

Comment: This was blowing my mind.  The key here is that the Comma operator "returns the value of the last operand" - the "value" here is the function itself absent its containing parent - so foo no longer lives inside of a.

Comment: the function doesn't `return` true, rather logs true to console. Except for that, I liked this explanation more!

Comment: is it safe to write this kind of code then?:
`const obj = {
  name: "kyle",
  printName(){
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}
`

Answer (score 7):

Calling a function in this roundabout way:

```
(throwAwayValueHere, fn)(args);
```

works like this:

- The comma expression `throwAwayValueHere, fn` is evaluated: The comma operator evaluates its first operand, throws away that value, then evaluates its second operand and takes that value as its result.
- That value is then called as a function, passing in the arguments.

Doing the call that way has an effect in two situations:

1. If the function is on an object property, e.g.:

```
(throwAwayValueHere, obj.fn)(args);
```

it calls the function *without* setting `this` to `obj` during the function call; instead, it's set to the default, either the global `this` value (`window` on browsers) or `undefined` in strict mode.

Example:

```js
"use strict";
const obj = {
    value: 42,
    fn: function() {
        console.log(`typeof this = ${typeof this}`);
        if (typeof this === "object") {
            console.log(`this.value = ${this.value}`);
        }
    }
};

// Normal call:
console.log(`obj.fn():`);
obj.fn();

// Indirect call:
console.log(`(0, obj.fn)():`);
(0, obj.fn)();
```

This is the reason Babel is doing it there: In the original code, the call was simply `a()`, which calls `a` with the default `this` value. Doing `(0, _b.a)()` does the same thing even though `a` is a property of `_b`.

2. If the function is `eval`, it makes it an *indirect `eval`* which means it's evaluated as though at global scope, rather than `eval`'s default behavior of running arbitrary code from a string in *local* scope, giving it access to all in-scope variables.

Example:

```js
"use strict";

let a = "global a";

function directEval() {
    let a = "local a";
    eval("console.log(`a = ${a}`);");
}

function indirectEval() {
    let a = "local a";
    (0,eval)("console.log(`a = ${a}`);");
}

console.log("direct:");
directEval();
console.log("indirect:");
indirectEval();
```