# Unexplained pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've come across this pattern:

```
(0, _inherits3.default)(SpecRunner, _File);
```

I can't completely wrap my mind around it -- to me it looks like the comma operator is being used, which would evalute the expressions inside the first pair of parentheses from left to right and return the last expression, in this case `inherits3.default`. In case this is a callable, it would call it with the arguments `SpecRunner` and `_File`.

Is my analysis correct and if so, why would someone, instead of writing,

```
_inherits3.default(SpecRunner, _File);
```

use such a pattern?

Comment: Out of curiosity's sake, is the context available? EDIT: [yes](https://github.com/cotto89/squads/blob/dc72b58531a0e3e7613d1d137164d2061cbc2c2c/dist/helper/errors.js#L48).. I wonder, since it's the output of some transpiler..

Comment: That looks like something that a transpiler might emit.

Comment: possible better dupe target: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275135/why-does-babel-rewrite-imported-function-call-to-0-fn

Comment: The effect is that the value of `this` in the function will be the default value instead of the `_inherits3` object. As to why, you'd need to ask the one who wrote it.

Comment: @squint `undefined`, not the `.default` itself

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, I can see how what I wrote could be confusing. I meant the default `this` value that gets assigned when there's no definite object ot use, so either `undefined` or the global object when not in strict mode.