# MUI Strange Code in Button Component , hope anyone can explain

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui, babeljs

this is some code from material UI [githubs mui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js)
line 13

after bable2016 compiled this code is like:

`(0, _extends2.default)({}, theme.typography.button, ...)`

what's this grammer ? anyone ever seem?

whole section after compiled . the compile is successed but I am still comfused
    var _extends2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/helpers/extends"));

```
  root: (0, _extends2.default)({}, theme.typography.button, {
      boxSizing: 'border-box',
      minWidth: 64,
      minHeight: 36,
      padding: '8px 16px',
      borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
      color: theme.palette.text.primary,
      transition: theme.transitions.create(['background-color', 'box-shadow', 'border'], {
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.short
      }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in the first part of the following

```
(0, _extends2.default)({}, theme.typography.button, ...)
```

is using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

The reason for using it is explained here: [Why does babel rewrite imported function call to (0, fn)(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275135/why-does-babel-rewrite-imported-function-call-to-0-fn/32275207#32275207).

Except for subtleties regarding `this` that don't matter in this case, it is basically equivalent to the following:

```
_extends2.default({}, theme.typography.button, ...);
```

The use of the `extends` function is replacing the use of [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) for including everything in `theme.typography.button` in Button's "root" style rule. `extends` is very similar to [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).