# what is (0, c.default) and what is it doing in this code?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, base64, hex

completely new to reactJS, I wanted to understand what `(0, c.default)` is doing on this code snippet. the code apparently converts **hexadecimal** value to **Base64**. but before converting it to the **Base64** it was converted as **string** then but I didn't understand what this code doing `(0, c.default)`?

**Here is the code snippet**

```
f = t.type + "&" + encodeURIComponent(t.url) + "&" + n + "&" + u + "&" + b + 
                                "&LS8goCQy4O2w5xnPmEOp/PjtKe37+d9HxRthqug9VC0=";
sig = hexToBase64((0, c.default)(f).toString())
```

Here is the code snippet of the method **hexToBase64()**

```
hexToBase64: function (o) {
                return t.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, o.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")))
```

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32275135/3001761?

Comment: It's basically `c.default.call(globalThis, f).toString()`. Essentially it ensures that `c.default`'s `this` will not be `c` as it would normally be when writing `c.default(f)`, but the global `this` (`globalThis` in modern JS, same as e.g. `window` in a browser).

Comment: @CherryDT thanks for the clarification, now I can understand it.