# Function call prefixed by a number

Tags: javascript, function

I was going through the source of [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) and I stumbled upon this piece of code:

```
    const pass = (0, _jasmineUtils.equals)(received, expected, [
      _utils.iterableEquality
    ]);
```

What is the zero doing in front of this function call? Can this value somehow be accessed in the `_jasmineUtils.equals` function? If so, how? I tried it out myself in a little script, and it does *not* show up in `arguments`.

What kind of Javascript function calling mechanism is used here? Does it have a name?

Comment: Also see here for why it can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59124936/why-does-any-javascript-code-want-to-cut-the-binding

Comment: nice tip @NickParsons, appreciated!