# Comma expression typescript 4.4.x output

Tags: typescript, typescript4.0

I have the following input:

```js
import {onMediaChangeSubscribe} from '../functions/doOnMediaChange'

export class ActionButton extends ElementBase {
    mount(){
        onMediaChangeSubscribe(this.render)
    }
}
```

The output of typescript 4.3.x is:

```js
doOnMediaChange_1.onMediaChangeSubscribe(this.render);
```

And typescript 4.4.x do the following:

```js
(0, doOnMediaChange_1.onMediaChangeSubscribe)(this.render);
```

W̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶h̶a̶c̶k̶?̶?̶?̶
My question is partially answered here: [JavaScript syntax (0, fn)(args)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541134/javascript-syntax-0-fnargs), but I would like to clarify.

**Why there is such a change in TypeScript?**

---

Minimal reproduction example:

`a.ts`

```js
export function doTheThing(){}
```

`b.ts`

```js
import {doTheThing} from './a'

doTheThing()
```

b.ts compiles to:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var a_1 = require("./a");
(0, a_1.doTheThing)();
```

Used `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you can’t give us a [mre] it’s hard to know how to help.  Can you examine the project configuration to see if you can configure the TS playground similarly?

Comment: What's the question? "What the hack???" is not a real question.

Comment: @jcalz, Heretic Monkey – Done.

Comment: Okay, I think I've answered "Why there is such a change in TypeScript?" assuming that's the actual question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This change was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#44624](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44624) as a fix to [microsoft/TypeScript#35420](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35420), and was released with TypeScript 4.4.  (Note that there was an earlier fix attempt at [microsoft/TypeScript#35877](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35877) but this was reverted in [microsoft/TypeScript#43993](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43993) before it was released.)

As the answer to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541134/javascript-syntax-0-fnargs) explains, the difference between `foo.bar()` and `(0, foo.bar)()` is that the `this` context of the former is `foo`, while in the latter it is `undefined` (in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), or the global object in sloppy mode).  `foo.bar()` treats `bar` as a *method* of `foo`, while `(0, foo.bar)()` treats `bar` as a *function* unrelated to `foo`.

Depending on TypeScript's [module target](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#code-generation-for-modules), the emitted Javascript will put imported things into an object, so

```
import {onMediaChangeSubscribe} from '../functions/doOnMediaChange'
```

could be emitted as

```
const doOnMediaChange_1 = require("../functions/doOnMediaChange")
```

And then any reference to `onMediaChangeSubscribe` needs to be emitted as  `doOnMediaChange_1.onMediaChangeSubscribe`.

When you call an imported function, you want it to act like a function and not a "method" of the module you're importing.  Well, much of the time there's no difference, but if the body of the imported function happens to make reference to `this`, you really want that `this` to be `undefined` and not `doOnMediaChange_1`, or else it won't be equivalent to the behavior of native modules.

That was essentially the problem in microsoft/TypeScript#35420. The fix is to just universally wrap calls to imported functions with the comma operator, as you've seen.