# Why Typescript compiler adds extra (0, expression) to output?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation

Lately I had to debug a test that had been written in TypeScript and has been run via `ts-mocha`.
So, actually I had to debug the transpiler output sorta directly.
And in lines like this:

```js
(0, expect_1.default)(loadedTask.name).toBe(newTask.name);
```

only this `(0, expression)` wrapping got me confused.
What is purpose of this `(0, expr)` wrapping?
What JS gotcha this wrapping should prevent or workaround?

Thanks for your answers and time.

Comment: It's to produce spec-compliant imports so that imported functions would have the proper `this` context.  See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69633435/2887218) to the linked question for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I just was not able to ask the question the proper way at search bar, although I tried few different variants, before asking the question. It surely answers and brings sense to `(0,expr)` syntax. JS may be need some "access without `this` operator like  `->` or `:>` to explicitly say to JS compiler what it is about,  and to process this faster .