# What does (0, function_identifier)() do in javascript?

Tags: javascript

*Sorry for ambiguous title. I totally don't know the reason behind this nor it's technique name.*

I was browsing in nextjs code then I ran into something weird (in my pov).

```js
class NextTracerImpl {
   trace() {...}
...
}

const getTracer = (() => {
   const tracer = new NextTracerImpl();
   return () => tracer;
})();

// this is my question
(0, _tracer.getTracer)().trace(...)
```

Why it shouldn't be like:

```js
const getTracer = () => {
   const tracer = new NextTracerImpl();
   return tracer;
};

_tracer.getTracer.trace(...)
```

Comment: `getTracer` returns a function, so you have to call it ... so, it'd be `_tracer.getTracer().trace(...)` at least ... but what even is `_tracer`? `(0, _tracer.getTracer)` is some convoluted way of doing `_tracer.getTracer` ... so, in effect, the code you are asking about does `_tracer.getTracer().trace(...)`

Comment: [JavaScript syntax (0, fn)(args)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541134/javascript-syntax-0-fnargs)

Comment: It's basically a convoluted way of breaking `this` binding from dot notation.  eg.  `class A { foo() { console.log('this = ' + this); }}; var a  = new A(); a.foo(); (0,a.foo)(); var b = a.foo; b();`  It's similar to doing `var a = obj.method`,  `a()`, and finding `a` has lost it's `this`

Comment: Its a little bit more complicated.  The IIFE on the RHS of the assignment to  `getTrace `creates a singleton instance class `NextTracerImpl` and returns an arrow function that returns the singleton when getTracer is called.  If the class is intended to create a singleton instance that makes sense. The arrow function uses the `this` value current when `getTracer` was assigned a value. However the actual use of `(0, _tracer.getTracer)().trace(...)` to get a function reference that can be called with an undefined `this` is superfluous when calling an arrow function.

Comment: @traktor Super usefull thank you