# Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects

Tags: typescript

I am running this function on TypeScript and I get this error

```
`Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects`
```

```
function groupBy(data) {

  const mapper = new Map()
    
  for (const { Name, Department } of data) {
    if (!mapper.has(Department))
     mapper.set(Department, { title: Department, people: [] })
    mapper.get(Department).people.push(Name)
  }

 return Array.from(mapper, ([title, people]) => (title, people))
}
```

All of this works fine on normal JS so there must be something about TS

[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WyveZw)

Working on regular JS

```js
const data = [{ Name: 'Peter',Department: 'Finance'},{Name: 'Jane',Department: 'HR'},{Name: 'Tom',Department: 'Finance'}]

function groupBy(data) {

  const mapper = new Map()
  for (const { Department, Name} of data) {
    if (!mapper.has(Department)) mapper.set(Department, { title: Department, people: []}) 
    mapper.get(Department).people.push(Name)
  }

  return Array.from(mapper, ([title, people]) => (title, people))
}

console.log(groupBy(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

##### UPDATE

Thanks to Aleksey L

This works great and gives no TS error

```
Array.from(mapper.values())
```

Or

```
[...mapper.values()]
```

Comment: `(title, people)`? Should this be `({title, people})` or what?

Comment: Of the return array, is what the for loop does, creates an array of objects `{ title: string, people: []}` They are contained in the `mapper` Map object

Comment: Also shouldn't `mapper.get(Department).push(Name)` be `mapper.get(Department).people.push(Name)`?

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, that fixed the second problem

Comment: _All of this works fine on normal JS so there must be something about TS_ No, it doesn't work in "normal JS"

Comment: Now it does, made a mistake sorry

Comment: @AlekseyL. I agree, neither [the comma operator version](https://jsbin.com/dixavawaqi/1/edit?js,console), nor [the one that returns an object](https://jsbin.com/gegerotewa/1/edit?js,console) works in JS.

Comment: Yeah, now after the fix it works the same in typescript, it just tells you that `title, ` is useless

Comment: ...there is the same bug in JS but since you don't use a linter, you've not noticed it. [What does a comma do in JavaScript expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561043) | [Comma operator returns first value instead of second in argument list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5580596). `(title, people)` should be `people`

Comment: @AlekseyL. but I need the `title` otherwise it wont return the same array

Comment: What are you trying to do with `return Array.from(mapper, ([title, people]) => (title, people))` ?

Comment: BTW, If you click run in TS playground it prints exactly the same result

Comment: I am trying to do what I do on the JS snippet

Comment: @Álvaro *You are not returning the title!* The code `(title, people)` will *do nothing* with `title` and then return `people`. Since you say the JS version "works", obviously you don't need `title`, as it's not used.

Comment: I see `return Array.from(mapper, ([_,people]) => (people))` this works

Comment: You can simplify to `return Array.from(mapper.values())` then

Comment: typescript is complaining that the title on the left side of the comma doesnt do anything so it redundant in the way you wrote it. please explain in clear terms what you are trying to get from the function as its return value, because it really depends on what your intention is, and it can be many things in this scenario. for example, you could return an object by doing `return Array.from(mapper, ([title, people]) => ({title, people}))`

Comment: I was tryin to return an object yes, and your sugestion fixes it, thanks